# Why does the accepted answer mark have different color schemes?

Tags: discussion

I found this out on different Stack Exchange sites:

[image: First Mark] 
[image: Second mark] 
[image: Third mark]

- [Link 1](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174/are-hardware-dongles-able-to-protect-your-software) ([Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tour))
- [Link 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ([Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour))
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327497/meaning-of-stackoverflow-in-c-programming) ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour))

Why?

Comment: I feel like this is answered elsewhere, but short answer until it's found: Because the sites have different themes and styles, and it just happens that part of that is also the check mark style.

Comment: Many communities have their own custom styling to better reflect the atmosphere of the community.  For example, badge shapes/icons also differ from community to community.  This might already have a better answer on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9):

For the same reasons that each Stack Exchange Site has its own design.  The checkmark is part of that overall design.

You wouldn't put a Chrysler hubcap on a Prius, would you?

Comment: @yellowantphil: Does Yello want Phil, or is Yellow an ant phil?

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you yell "ow ant phil" I'll tell you.