# Why are questions about the details of compiler behavior downvoted and closed?

Tags: discussion

I feel misunderstood on most of my questions. People downvote me (some upvote me too), or vote to close, or are rude or unpleasant to talk to, and I'd like to know how I could do better.

If my question is too broad please tell me what I should have done - this is the meta, if I can't ask here, I can't ask anywhere.

**#1**
The most obvious one is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119976/what-could-happen-practically-on-undefined-behavior-in-c). I am asking a question about what does happen **in practice** with undefined behavior. I won't use it in my code, it is only for curiosity and for betting understanding of computing internals.

- First comment talks about theory. LOL.
- I got threatened "Still wondering whether to vote for close as being too broad."
- Got downvoted
- Got several answers and comments where people just tell me not to use UB in my code. "10,000 customers [...] will want their money back talk to their lawyers if you do this". I don't want to do this, I want to learn.
- Few answers try to really answer me

Am I not allowed to post question about bad practices in order to learn?

I know my question was broad, but should I really have spammed Stack Overflow by creating seven posts? If I did so, people would have blamed me not showing research effort.

I wrote this in the question:

> You obviously cannot get root by doing a signed integer overflow.

I voluntarily omitted obvious details. I know that if kernel is really broken you could get root by doing `i++`. An user wrote a full answer about it. Yet his answer was interesting, should I have put even more details in my questions?

**#2** Why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982618/vim-does-not-support-filename-modifiers-on-android) closed? It's precise and was even answered in comments!

**#3** Why do you think people did downvote me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718382/how-to-run-a-program-with-no-arguments)? Even if final vote count is zero.

**#4** In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099374/no-compiler-warning-for-obvious-segfault), I ask about GCC warnings, and the first comments are rude. Some user tells me to apply for a Nobel prize, then asks me to show a reference to the C standard where it says there has to be a warning for it. I never said there should be a warning, I want to understand the spirit behind it, why implementors did decide it. Now it got it! Answers and comments were helpful, but still there were rude people.

**#5** The same user annoys me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41418766/is-it-legal-to-pass-a-non-null-terminated-string-to-strncmp-in-c). I saw contradictions between different references/manuals so I thought it was a good idea to ask. He tells me to update my man pages, which is silly because if I have some man pages, lots of people will have the same, and I thought man pages were a safe reference (also, they were up to date). Can't he just answer the question or say nothing?

**#6** I didn't got the Stack Overflow spirit at the time, and I didn't knew about communities when [posting this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335838/why-does-the-accepted-answer-mark-have-different-color-schemes). Answers and comments have helped me to understand better how it works. Why so many downvotes?

**#7** Why would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998226/how-to-disable-specific-gcc-note) be a XY problem? Maybe I just spend more attention to details than you.

Comment: I wrote `If my question is too broad please tell me what I should have done` then I get DV and close-voted without reason. Helpful. Just wanted to improve my questions

Comment: I mean your question here is pretty much the definition of too broad. You're asking 7 different questions, none of them really related to each other. The close reason states *"Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."*. You can certainly ask on meta how to improve your questions but try to focus on one at a time. That being said, some of these questions aren't really issues that would (currently) require a question on meta: #2) You got one down and one upvote. Nobody here will be able to tell you why exactly someone downvoted.

Comment: #4 I don't see a question here. If you think a comment is rude you can flag it. I wouldn't be surprised if it was declined though, as I don't really see anything rude in those comments. #5 Again, I don't know what anyone here on meta should say about that. I don't see anything wrong with his comments either. His man-pages don't show the same as yours so he's asking if you maybe just need to update yours.

Comment: Questions need to have an actual purpose.  This is not the correct place for asking out something of curiosity.

Comment: Too many questions being asked here for me to even think about giving you specific advice, but you should feel free to ignore Olaf. He's a very capable C programmer, and I believe he means well, but he can be very hostile in comments. It is a known problem. Don't take the rudeness personally.

Comment: Some of the questions seem to be desinged to annoy professional/enthusiast programmers.  The question alluded to in '#5 The same user annoys me here.' is, essentially, 'how do I stop the compiler telling me stuff I already know;' , I mean, how is the compiler supposed to know that you know?  (does that even make any sense?).

Comment: As for the alleged 'rudeness', how would you describe a multi-part question specualting about the behaviour of something that you already know is wrong?  Just how is that useful to future visitors/users?  Every week, we get some poster asking to 'explain exactly what is happening' with a UB question, and is unwilling to accept 'nobody knows' as an answer.  I assume this is because their homework is prefaced with 'Explain all your answers fully', and so they insist, over and over and over...  We're tired of it, and it's understadable if some comments eventually seem a bit ratty;(

Comment: @MartinJames This could be useful to future visitors like me who don't have to do homework anymore for years, know a bit of theory, but are curious about wrong behaviors, maybe like a doctor who wants to understand illnesses

Comment: @Bilow: For what it's worth, the big problem with #1 is this: it's *always changing*. What a particular compiler does with UB can change from version to version. A change to how functions are inlined could affect what happens. A change to general optimizations can affect what happens. And so on. UB exists in C/C++ so that compilers have the freedom to make UB-free code as fast as possible. Exactly how that happens *cannot be predicted*.

Comment: For example, here's yet another one insisting on an explanation for UB: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46133267/758133

Comment: @MartinJames The user says himself he's newbie. I'm not and insist purposely. This is not comparable.

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through these one by one:

**#1**: There are way too many questions in this post, which reduces the helpfulness for other users.  You should stick to one specific question per post.  Not seven.

**#2**: This is not a question about programming.  Even if you use `vim` as your programming tool, the question is about `vim`, not about programming, and thus does not belong on SO.  (It might be on-topic on our sister site [Super User](https://superuser.com/)).

**#3**: Hard to say, not being a C expert, but I reckon this is more a question about the shell than about programming itself.

**#4**: We do have a [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy on this site.  You should flag posts that do not abide by it.  Question seems reasonable, though I can't work out which comment you're talking about here.

**#5**: Again, not a C expert, but I wouldn't think that comment is being rude.  I think it's a well-intentioned suggestion.

**#6**: Not even sure what you're asking here.

**#7**: Your real problem isn't that this note keeps appearing, it's the fact that your `a` variable is undefined.  Fix that, and the other note goes away.

Comment: On #2 the help centre advises that questions about *software tools commonly used by programmers* (and if Vim ain't one of those, what is ?) may be asked on SO (subject to all the usual caveats that only good questions can be asked).  So I disagree with #2 here, and agree with @Bilow.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark the line is a bit vague. I believe the help center means that questions about compilers, IDEs, testing suites and such are on topic. `vim` is just a text editor, and has little to do with programming (except that programmers tend to use it). So I can understand it being off-topic (most programmers tend to either use Linux, Windows or macOS, but general questions about them are off-topic too).

Comment: There is also https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *the line is a bit vague. I believe the help center means ...*  Well, yes, that's rather the point.  A relatively new user is entitled to be confused about whether questions concerning the use of Vim in the practice of programming are welcome here or not.  As I (and a few others I think) read and interpret matters, they are.

Comment: If it were a question about `vim` in a programming context, I would probably be fine with it.  This question though is not.